# How does the "route" utility make sense of the data in /proc/net/route?

Tags: manjaro, iproute, hex

result of `cat /proc/net/route`:

```
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT                                                       
wlo1    00000000        0100A8C0        0003    0       0       600     00000000        0       0       0                                                                             
wlo1    0000A8C0        00000000        0001    0       0       600     00FFFFFF        0       0       0
```

result of `route`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

I am sensing that some kind of hex codes are being used, but I am still not able to understand how 0100A8C0 translates to `_gateway` (same for the rest).

Comment: If you [look at the source](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools/blob/master/route.c), it reads the kernel structures directly. It doesn't directly parse the pseudofile that the kernel provides in `/proc/`.

Comment: I didn't know `route` uses `/proc`. I always assumed it uses *netlink*.

Answer (score 2):

`0000A8C0` is just the integer representation of your IP address 192.168.0.0, written in hexadecimal; check it yourself: C0<sub>16</sub> = 192<sub>10</sub> and A8<sub>16</sub>=168<sub>10</sub>.

> how 0100A8C0 translates to _gateway

It doesn't, it is identical to 192.168.0.1

Comment: Ah! that's back to front? Also, what about stuff like `0003 -> UG`?

Comment: yeah the endianness was surprising. For statements on these mappings, refer to the kernel docs or the procfs source code.

Comment: The numbers are all rather funny, try `ping 2130706454` and be prepared to be amazed...

Comment: @Bib shouldn't that be an odd number?? need to test.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, nope, remember, all of 127/8 can be pinged!

Comment: @Bib ah, true, so while they say there's no place like 2130706433, there's in fact 0xFFFF that are pretty similar

Comment: Oooh, `ping 0x7f000016` works as well.