# Where does `ip addr` get its data from?

Tags: iproute

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/iproute2/iproute2/blob/main/ip/ipaddress.c#L2269) and am stuck after line 2269. I have a feeling that just like [route](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767443/how-does-the-route-utility-make-sense-of-the-data-in-proc-net-route), this utility also, is using the procfs filesystem but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: `man 7 rtnetlink`. It doesn't need procfs.

Comment: `strace` is your friend when trying to find out what kernel API a command is using.

Comment: Now maybe you're looking for something else? How to use JSON (Including with `ip route`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a feeling that just like route

I am almost certain that no implementation of `route` on Linux uses procfs. The one in the linked question certainly doesn't, as [this comment explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767443/how-does-the-route-utility-make-sense-of-the-data-in-proc-net-route#comment1464224_767443):

> If you [look at the source](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools/blob/master/route.c), it reads the kernel structures directly. It doesn't directly parse the pseudofile that the kernel provides in `/proc/`.

There will be generally three types of implementations of `route`:

- Implementations created from scratch after the introduction of Netlink would be using Netlink.
- Implementations created before the introduction of Netlink would be using ioctl.
- Some implementations provide `route` as a simple wrapper around `ip route`.

> this utility also, is using the procfs filesystem

The entire iproute2 suite of tools uses Netlink. In fact, Netlink and iproute2 were developed roughly at the same time and Netlink was developed specifically to be used by network configuration tools such as iproute2.

In fact, both Netlink and iproute2 were originally developed by Alexey Kuznetsov, who developed both Netlink and iproute2 because the traditional networking configuration tools were hard to extend with support for QoS (which he also developed).